# jQuery: generate unique random color that hasn't been used already

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/8ysuw/

```
Colors.random = function() {
    var result;
    var count = 0;
    for (var prop in this.names)
        if (Math.random() < 1/++count)
           result = prop;
    return { name: result, rgb: this.names[result]};
};
```

I want to make sure that the same color doesn't appear once it's been called. Currently it will just keep on generating random color regardless and the same color shows at times.

In addition, I need to clear all the colors that have been used before, so the whole process can start from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Colors.called = {};
Colors.random = function () {
    var keys   = Object.keys(this.names),
        max    = keys.length,
        called = Object.keys(this.called),
        color  = keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - 0)) + 0];

    if (Colors.called[color]) {
        if (max === called.length) {
            Colors.called = {};    
        }

        return Colors.random();             
    }

    Colors.called[color] = true;
    return { name: color, rgb: this.names[color] };
};
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8ysuw/75/

Answer (score 1):

You could fill an array with all the color codes/names (unsure which one you need) and remove the selected element before you return it.

```
var colorFactory = (function () {
    var allColors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
    var colorsLeft = allColors.slice(0);

    return {
        getRandomColor: function () {
            if (colorsLeft.length === 0) {
                return undefined;
            }

            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsLeft.length);
            var color = colorsLeft[index];
            colorsLeft.splice(index, 1);
            return color;
        },
        reset: function () {
            colorsLeft = allColors.slice(0);
        }
    };
}());

// Usage:
// Get a random color
var someColor = colorFactory.getRandomColor();

// Reset: mark all colors as unused
colorFactory.reset();
```